# How does the inbuilt Workout app on Apple Watch navigate from main table row to a set of page-based controllers?

Tags: swift, watchkit, apple-watch

I was trying to mimic the Workout app for practise. And I got stuck at figuring out how to do this navigation from these table rows in the main screen to the 3/4 Workout starting screens which are page-based and seem to be hierarchical, with a back button on top left. They are most certainly not Modal as they do not appear from the bottom.

[image: Interface controller with table] -  -  ->   [image]

However I did not find any way to connect a row to a set of page-based interface controllers with push segue.

This is what I tried:

1- presentController(withNames:, contexts:) which presents the page-based layout MODALLY.

```
override func table(_ table: WKInterfaceTable, didSelectRowAt rowIndex: Int) {
        let controllers = controllersForExercise(categories[rowIndex])
        presentController(withNames: controllers, contexts: nil)
    }

func controllersForExercise(_ exercise: Exercise) -> [String] {
        // Returns a bunch of Identifiers (from Storyboard) as [String]
    }
```

2- In the storyboard, I connected the table row to the first of these page-based interface controllers by a push segue, and then connected that controller to the other three page-based interface controllers sequentially using nextPage segue (relationship).
[image]
This did not work. It just segues with the back button on top left but showed only the first interface controller, not the other three as page-based controllers.
I am assuming it is happening because table row selection makes it a hierarchical navigation while this is a page-based navigation, and the two cannot be mixed according to Apple.

So I am baffled about how Apple manages it themselves. Any clues?

Comment: Please check out this tutorial by AppCoda: http://www.appcoda.com/selectable-table-watchkit/

Comment: @Xcoder123 The above tutorial shows how to navigate from a table row to a single controller, NOT a set of page-based controllers (which is my query).

Comment: sorry, my mistake

Comment: Quite often Apple apps use private APIs to do some things that otherwise couldn't be done. This might be one example.

Comment: I'm trying to implement this using swiftUI would it be possible for you to [help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58509975/using-multiple-hosting-controllers-in-swiftui-on-watchos) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OBJC:

```
+ (void)reloadRootPageControllersWithNames:(NSArray<NSString *> *)names 
                              contexts:(NSArray *)contexts 
                           orientation:(WKPageOrientation)orientation 
                             pageIndex:(NSInteger)pageIndex;
```

SWIFT:

```
class func reloadRootPageControllers(withNames names: [String], 
                        contexts: [Any]?, 
                     orientation: WKPageOrientation, 
                       pageIndex: Int)
```

Comment: I'm trying to implement this using swiftUI would it be possible for you to [help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58509975/using-multiple-hosting-controllers-in-swiftui-on-watchos) ?