# Using multiple hosting controllers in SwiftUI on WatchOS

Tags: swift, swiftui, apple-watch, watchos, watchos-6

I'm trying to use multiple `WKHostingController` in a SwiftUI WatchOS project.

I want to be able to go from one Controller to 3 controllers.

[image]

The user will press a button in the first `ContentView(1)` (That is paired with `HostingController(1)`) that will then navigate them to the middle controller in the 3-grouped set `HC3` (or `HostingController3`, with Identifier `HC3`)

The Code is as follows:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            NavigationLink(destinationName: "HC3"){
                Text("Go to other wk")
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Hosting Controller :

```
class HostingController: WKHostingController<AnyView> {
    override var body: AnyView {
        return AnyView(ContentView())
    }
}
```

That does take me to `HC3` But I cannot navigate to `HC2` or `HC4` to create multiple page view where the user can scroll between `HC2`, `HC3` and `HC4`. HostingController 2-4 all have similar HostingControllers and ContentViews as the ones above.

I have also made sure that `HC2`, `HC3` and  `HC4` have the Relationship `Next Page` linearly 
`HC2 -> HC3 -> HC4`

If I check the initial controller checkbox for `HC2` in the Attributes Inspector I am able to navigate between `HC2`, `HC3` and `HC4` as expected, but if I check the initial controller checkbox for `HC3` I am only able to navigate between `HC3` and `HC4` even when the same `HC2 -> HC3 -> HC4` relationships exist.

I'm having two issues, the first (1) Navigating from `HC1` to `HC3` where `HC3` has the Relationship `Next Page` intact ( meaning I can scroll through `HC2 HC3 HC4` the second(2) Being able to have a middle Hosting controller keep it's relationship where it is a `Next Page` to another HostingController.

Any ideas how I can make this work ?