# How does SwiftUI pass EnvironmentObjects between HostingController?

Tags: swiftui, watchkit

I am trying to implement an Apple Watch app in a similar way as this question:
[Issues implementing navigation from a main controller to page based controllers in WatchOS using SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58546593/issues-implementing-navigation-from-a-main-controller-to-page-based-controllers)

I am trying to pass data between different `HostingController`s. My data is stored in an `EnvironmentObject` with published properties. If I only use one `HostingController`, it's fine to share data between the different views. But when using a different `HostingController`, hosting different views (without segues), I can't find the syntax for using my `Environment` object from `HC1` to `HC2`, the `HC3`, etc.

I present the `HostingController` using this piece of code in my SwiftUI views.

```
NavigationLink(destinationName: "HC2"){
        Text("Go to HC2")
```

Comment: What approach did you go for in the end? I'm facing the exact same issue.

Comment: I have used this approach which fits my needs. But now, I have another issue. I don't know how to go back to the first HostingController from HC3 or HC4

Comment: @bencallis, did you ever find a workable solution for this? I have multiple UIHostingControllers in a navigationcontroller that I want to share data between.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is possible approach

```
class AppState: ObservableObject {
    static let shared = AppState()      // shared instance

    @Published var setting: String = "some"
}

class HostingController: WKHostingController<AnyView> {
    override var body: AnyView {
        let contentView = ContentView()
            .environmentObject(AppState.shared)     // << inject !!
        return AnyView(contentView)
    }
}

class HostingController2: WKHostingController<AnyView> {
    override var body: AnyView {
        let contentView = ContentView2()
            .environmentObject(AppState.shared)     // << inject !!
        return AnyView(contentView)
    }
}
```

Comment: Are there any other approaches? Resorting to using global shared data really doesn't seem ideal.